# Stored Procedure outlining

Tags: visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures, outlining

I have stored procedure (unorganized - not properly outlined)

I want automatic outlining in the stored procedure by using VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sqlinform.com/free_online_sw.html

Try this, or google "SQL Indentation"

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own template file which you then load in.

[http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/visual-studio-how-to-create-item-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897203/stored-procedure-outlining/2897339#2897339)